# HyperV Ubuntu Server with Hestia/CloudPanel development server?

Tags: windows, vpn, ip, hyper-v, linux-server

I use Window 10 as Host.

VM is Ubuntu Server.

I want to use either Hestia or Cloudpanel.

**The problem:**

After installation I can login from the Windows 10 host via browser with `hostname:8443` or `192.177.155.65:8443`. This stays the same but Hestia/CloudPanel shows in back-end my public host's IP (the IP you get if you're visiting [www.whatsmyip.com](https://www.whatsmyip.com) or similar), because I'm using an external switch to connect to the internet and for that reason every domain I create won't work.

It's not possible to create another external switch because I only have one network adapter in my system.

**I tried:**

Static IP but I lost my network at the host and honestly I'm a little bit clueless about what I'm looking for in the end.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?
It's only for development.

Comment: There is an approach that you modify the network device in Windows 10 itself, this I tried. The solution is maybe sth. like that vm thinks that its connected via 192.177.155.65 to the internet and not the random ip4 which I got assigned by my provider on connection.

Comment: But how? I can't find any solution without host side manipulations.